# Connected Sheet with BQ as source - Delegated Access Error

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

Perplexed with this as have run several other projects successfully.

I have a BigQuery database, that I connect to via Google Connected Sheets. In IAM, I am the only user and have given myself BigQuery Admin and Owner roles for the project.

I can setup the connection with preview and an extract in google sheets, but now cant edit the connection as I am presented with the message "Delegate access - You do not have permission to delegate access for this BigQuery project.

I have gotten the owner of the domain to go into the admin console of google, and they could not locate any relevant Delegation access authorisation toggles.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.